# Rails 6 has many via multiple joins

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, has-many

Technology: Rails/ActiveRecord 6.1.x

Ultimately it may be that there is no normal way to do this but here is my goal:

Connect Table 1 via 4 joins to Table 2 where ultimately Table 1 has_many  on Table 2. Here is an example:

```
Table1 = Person ( has many pets )
Join1 = Pet ( belongs to person, has many pet toys )
Join2 = PetToy ( belongs to pet, belongs to toy maker )
Join3 = ToyMaker ( has many pet toys, belongs to investing company )
Join4 = InvestingCompany ( has many toy makers, belongs to ceo )
Table2 = CEO ( has many investing companies )
```

I want to have something like 'has many :ceos' in 'Person'. But the jump at 'PetToy' is causing me trouble.
I can use 'delegate xyz to abc' to get from an Instance of PetToy with `.ceo` to return the Table 2 Ceo. And I go from Person all the way to PetToys. But I am unsure how to bridge that gap to get the 'has_many' up a chain of 'belongs_to'.

Is it perhaps impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Table1 = Person ( has many pets )
Join1 = Pet ( belongs to person, has many pet toys )
Join2 = PetToy ( belongs to pet, belongs to toy maker )
Join3 = ToyMaker ( has many pet toys, belongs to investing company )
Join4 = InvestingCompany ( has many toy makers, belongs to ceo )
Table2 = CEO ( has many investing companies )

To get all the CEOs for a person this is the join.

```
Ceos.joins(companies: { toy_makers: { pet_toys: { pet: :people } } }
    .where(people: {id: person.id})
```

Depending on your needs you could also use has many through.

```
class Ceo {
    has_many :companies
    has_many :toy_makers, through: :companies
}
class ToyMaker {
    has_many :pet_toys
    has_many :people, through: :pet_toys
}
Ceos.joins(toy_makers: { :people }
    .where(people: {id: person.id})
```